# List of Dictionary Values match on Plain Dictionary; update the value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two variables one is a list of dictionaries and another one is a plane dictionary

1. we have to match the list of dictionaries "id" values with the plain dictionary key.
2. when the match is found update the list of dictionary name keys values
   based on plain dictionary values.

below are the references

```
lst1 = [{"id":"01","name":"michel","age":"30"},{"id":"02","name":"oliever","age":"29"},{"id":"04","name":"james","age":"28"}] #list of dictionaries

lst2 = {"01":"Surendra","02":"Ravi","03":"Ramu"}#Dictionary
```

when we print(lst1) the output will be like this

```
 O/p:[{'id': '01', 'name': 'Surendra', 'age': '30'}, {'id': '02', 'name': 'Ravi', 'age': '29'}, {'id': '04', 'name': 'james', 'age': '28'}]
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with a simple for loop over your list, replacing the values as you go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for l in lst1:
    if l[ 'id' ] in lst2:
        l[ 'name' ] = lst2[ l[ 'id' ] ]

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what if a match is not found.

Comment: lst1 = [{"id":"01","name":"michel","age":"30"},{"id":"04","name":"oliever","age":"29"},{"id":"03","name":"james","age":"28"}] #list of dictionaries
lst2 = {"01":"Surendra","02":"Ravi","03":"Ramu"}

Comment: o/p would be like this [{'id': '01', 'name': 'Surendra', 'age': '30'}, {'id': '04', 'name': 'oliever', 'age': '29'}, {'id': '03', 'name': 'Ramu', 'age': '28'}]

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = [
        {"id": "01", "name": "michel", "age": "30"},
        {"id": "04", "name": "oliever", "age": "29"},
        {"id": "03", "name": "james", "age": "28"}
        ]
lst2 = {"01": "Surendra", "02": "Ravi", "03": "Ramu"}

for l in lst1:
    if l['id'] in lst2:
        l['name'] = lst2[l['id']]

print(lst1)

[{'id': '01', 'name': 'Surendra', 'age': '30'}, {'id': '04', 'name': 'oliever', 'age': '29'},{'id': '03', 'name': 'Ramu', 'age': '28'}]
```